# host and docker nginx https setting

Tags: docker, nginx, https

Website use ubuntu lnmp, and host already set up https success.
port is 443.

`https://[subdomain_host.mydomain]/`

also have docker container in the machine. I want to change to https.

`https://[subdomain_docker.mydomain]:8080/`

The browser will show error message `ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR`

How do I fix it?

This is my nginx conf in docker container

```
server {
    gzip on;
    gzip_min_length 1k;
    gzip_buffers 4 16k;
    gzip_comp_level 2;
    gzip_types text/plain application/javascript application/x-javascript text/css application/xml text/javascript application/x-httpd-php image/jpeg image/gif image/png;
    gzip_vary off;
    gzip_disable "MSIE [1-6]\.";
    client_max_body_size 200m;

    root    /app/dist;
    index   index.html;

    location /api/ {
            rewrite         /api/(.*) /$1 break;
            proxy_pass      https://localhost:8000/;
    }

    listen              8080 ssl http2;
    server_name         [subdomain_docker.mydomain];
    ssl_certificate     /app/nginx/server.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /app/nginx/server.key;


    #enable ssl
    ssl                       on;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_ciphers      "EECDH+ECDSA+AESGCM EECDH+aRSA+AESGCM EECDH+ECDSA+SHA384 EECDH+ECDSA+SHA256 EECDH+aRSA+SHA384 EECDH+aRSA+SHA256 EECDH EDH+aRSA !aNULL !eNULL !LOW !3DES !MD5 !EXP !PSK !SRP !DSS !RC4";
}
```

Edit 1: change port 8080 to 443 in nginx conf , and run new container
by `docker run -d -p 8080:443 ...` , use `docker ps` to check

```
# docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                       NAMES
011b5e6fd12c        da8d                "/bin/bash /app/dock…"   7 seconds ago       Up 7 seconds        8000/tcp, 8080/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8080->443/tcp
```

use browser to see `https://[subdomain_docker.mydomain]`

but the result show the same as `https://[subdomain_host.mydomain]`, not `https://[subdomain_docker.mydomain]`

If I open `https://[subdomain_docker.mydomain]:8080/`,the web page show this

```
This site can’t provide a secure connection
[subdomain_docker.mydomain] sent an invalid response.
Try running Windows Network Diagnostics.
ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR
```

How to fix it?

Comment: You should change any `8080` port number in your `conf` files to `443`, then run your docker container like this: `docker run -dp8080:443 ...`. Try if it works

Comment: @Saeed I already use docker run -d -p 8080:443 ... but I don't know why show host website,not docker website.

Comment: `listen              8080 ssl http2` still remained untouched. Did you change it in your environment?

Comment: yes I already set it in docker nginx config, I think it could only read the host nginx conf